# Identifying the language of code

Tags: ansible

Can anyone tell me which language is this below code written, its actually used in one of my company ansible playbook

```
{% if item.boot.postscripts is defined %}
{% for post in item.boot.postscripts %}
{% include post %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be Jinja: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/

See also: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_templating.html

I'd advise you to contact the person who wrote it. Also, it's bound to be clear from the the rest of the code base that you're using.

Comment: Ansible templates are written in Jinja2: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_templating.html

Comment: @ctx Ah, there you go then. Thanks.